# Json variable in table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I'm trying to put content of a JSON in the  HTML table but content is filled in the rows ,and I would like to be filled in the columns.

My JSON :

```
var serie=
{

"keywords":[["CELL","CELL2","CELL3"]]
}
```

My JQuery code:

```
$.each(serie.keywords, function () {

    $.each(this, function (k,v) {
      var eachrow = "<tr>" 
                 + "<td>" + v + "</td>"
                 + "</tr>";
         $('#tbody').append(eachrow);

        }); 

});
```

As result I have soething like this:

```
CELL
-----
CELL2
-----
CELL3
```

And I would like that it will be like that:

```
CELL|CELL2|CELL3
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$.each(serie.keywords, function () { 

    var eachrow = "<tr>";

    $.each(this, function (k,v) {
        eachrow += "<td>" + v + "</td>";
    }); 
    eachrow += "</tr>";

    $('#tbody').append(eachrow);

});
```